# Writing a pickle.dumps output to a file

Tags: python, pickle

I have the following code:

```
some_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1}
line = "some_dict_b = %s\n" % pickle.dumps(some_dict,2)
exec(line)
decoded_dict = pickle.loads(some_dict_b)
decoded_dict == some_dict
```

In python 3 this code prints True. In python 2 (2.7.8) I get an error in the exec line. I know dumps returns str in 2.7 while it returns a byte-stream in 3.

I am writing a program that parses data from an input file then creates certain memory objects and should write out a python script that uses these objects. I write these objects in the script file using pickle.dumps() and inserting it into a variable declaration line as per the idea sketched above. But I need to be able to run this code in python 2.

I did notice that in python 3 the line variable gets each backslash properly escaped and a type:

```
>>> line
"some_dict_b = b'\\x80\\x02...
```

while in python 2 I get:

```
>>> line
'some_dict_b = \x80\x02...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3 `bytes` type doesn't *have* a string represention, so when converted to a string with `%s`, the *object representation* is used instead. If you wanted to produce Python-compatible syntax from objects, you can use the `%r` formatter instead, to just use the representation directly.

In Python 2:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> some_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1}
>>> p = pickle.dumps(some_dict, 2)
>>> print 'string: %s\nrepresentation: %r' % (p, p)
string: ?}q(UaqKUbqKu.
representation: '\x80\x02}q\x00(U\x01aq\x01K\x00U\x01bq\x02K\x01u.'
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> some_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1}
>>> p = pickle.dumps(some_dict, 2)
>>> print('string: %s\nrepresentation: %r' % (p, p))
string: b'\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x02K\x00u.'
representation: b'\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x02K\x00u.'
```

Object representations (the output of the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr), which uses the [`object.__repr__` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)) generally will attempt to provide you with a representation that can be pasted back into a Python script or interactive prompt to recreate the same value.

From the documentation for `repr()`:

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object.

None of this is specific to `pickle`, really.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation but why does the code work in python 3? Is it just a coincidence that then the string and representation views of the object agree?

Comment: @ErwinLavalliére: If there is no string representation (no `__str__` method) then `__repr__` is used instead. It was a coincidence that it worked at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you think "I use exec", think again. You don't. Instead of evaluating data like this, store the contents of the data inside a dict itself.

Then, assign the data explicit to the variable.

```
some_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1}
line = pickle.dumps(some_dict)
decoded_dict = pickle.loads(line)
decoded_dict == some_dict
```

Comment: I hit submit a bit early.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but that is not exactly what I want. You see, I would like to write the output of dumps in a python variable assignment statement, like this: "line = <dumps output>" that is to be executed later and even in another computer.

Comment: Why do you want this? Besides the security implications of exec (which are horrific), I don't believe you can have code that deals meaningful with arbitrarily created variables. So either you know which variables you need - then store their values and assign on load - or you don't, then you need a dynamic data structure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `repr` on the string or bytes object before inserting them into the line.

```
# Python 2
>>> 'some_dict = %s' % repr(pickle.dumps(d))
'some_dict = "(dp0\\nS\'a\'\\np1\\nI12\\nsS\'b\'\\np2\\nI24\\ns."'

# Python 3
>>> 'some_dict = %s' % repr(pickle.dumps(d))
"some_dict = b'\\x80\\x03}q\\x00(X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00bq\\x01K\\x18X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00aq\\x02K\\x0cu.'"
```

Or use the `format` method, using `!r` to automatically call `repr`:

```
>>> 'some_dict = {!r}'.format(pickle.dumps(d))
"some_dict = b'\\x80\\x03}q\\x00(X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00bq\\x01K\\x18X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00aq\\x02K\\x0cu.'"
```

(Also works in python 2)